# I used the built-in functions of node.js. How to fix "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_fs__.writeFile is not a function"

Tags: typescript

i creat a project about {typescript, react, electron, [gaea-editor](https://github.com/ascoders/gaea-editor.git)}

i use fs.writeFile() in an event
and then, it error.
like this `TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_fs__.writeFile is not a function`

if i just use `writeFile()` by node.js ,it can work.

system: win10

[myproject](https://gitee.com/magichan_gengcheng/ui-designer-react-demo.git)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import GaeaEditor from 'gaea-editor';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'> 
        <GaeaEditor onSave={value => this.newMethod(value)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

  private newMethod(value: any) {
    return fs.writeFile('D:/UI-designer/Filetest', value, 'utf-8', err => console.error(err));
  }
}
```

i hope it can work and no error

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS is a runtime for javascript on the server side, which means its not the same as JavaScript which runs on the client side (Browser), except the syntax.
`fs` is a NodeJS module which you cant use in the browser.
To write a file, your Component has to send an request to your backend (which runs nodeJS) and from there you can write to a file.